# Missing drivers to install Windows 7 on Ubuntu 18 Thinkpad

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, usb, multi-boot

I am trying to install Windows 7 on a dedicated partition on a *Thinkpad T460s* that is currently running Ubuntu 18. I created the partition with *gparted*, and I created the bootable USB using Rufus from a Windows PC.

Running *gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1* says that my disk is GPT.
These are my current partitions, the n1p4 should be dedicated to windows:

[image: partitions.png]

From the BIOS I deactivated secure boot and use UEFI. The USB boots properly, lets me pick language and keyboard layout and lets me click on the big Install button. The problem is at this point: the process stops, saying

> “A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing”

This is the error I get:

[image: missingDriver.jpg]

I know that the ISO I use is correct, because I tested it on a VM, so that should not be the problem. I tried creating the USB with different softwares, I tried unplugging it and plugging it back in, I tried changing USB port and I tried changing USB stick. Nothing helped.

At this point, I would be ok with having a clean *Windows* install and only afterwards putting Linux as dual boot, but given that I can't install *Windows* at all, this is currently not an option.

The best solution would be being able to install windows in the dedicated partition that I created. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This typically means you the installation environment was booted in UEFI mode thus requiring GPT but your HDD is MBR or vice versa.  So is your HDD MBR or GPT?  Edit your question to include this vital information

Comment: @Ramhound question updated, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Since you used Rufus what settings did you use and did you enable UEFI only mode?

Comment: @Ramhound UEFI only mode is active (question updated) and with Rufus I used the default settings: Standard Windows Install, GPT partitions scheme, UEFI target system, FAT32 file system and 4096 bytes cluster size.

Comment: Windows 7 cannot be installed from USB 3 devices without the appropriate driver being added.   Is your USB device USB 3 or USB 2?  This also might have something to do with the fact it’s NVMe.

Comment: @Ramhound the device is USB 2. I could try to make a bootable DVD, but I would have to use an external disk reader, and that would be connected with usb anyway.

Comment: So the problem is likely the lack of the appropriate driver for the NVMe device.

Comment: @Ramhound so where do I find it and how do I put it in place properly so that the install will finally work?

Comment: As I suggested, from [Lenovo](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t460s/downloads?linkTrack=Caps:Body_SearchProduct&searchType=3&keyWordSearch=T460s%20Laptop%20(ThinkPad)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85954/discussion-between-ramhound-and-john-doe).